# Changing from two heated O2 sensors to a single O2 sensor

Tags: o2-sensor, electronic-control-module, fuel-injection

I'm going to be removing a Motorcraft 2150 carburetor in a 2.8L V6 and swapping it for a Ford CFI (and ECU) from a 3.8L V6. I've just recently pulled everything (ECU, throttle body, sensors, harnesses, etc) from a Mercury Cougar.

When I was removing the CFI from the Cougar, I've noticed that the EEC-IV harness has two inputs for the heated O2 sensors (one in each manifold), but the 2.8L only has one O2 sensor (around the driver's side manifold).

- Is there a way to connect both O2 sensor inputs to a single O2 sensor? Or do I need to take off the other manifold and tap a hole into it?
- If I can connect both inputs to a single sensor, would it make any difference in the performance of it? Could the EEC-IV & CFI even make adjustments for each "side" of the engine? It does have separate injectors, but it seems like the air-fuel mixture would get combined in the intake after the CFI.

Comment: There is a lot of expense (from the point of view of an auto industry engineer and/or bean counter) in an extra O2 sensor and its support in the ECU, so I'd think that it is very likely that it does something useful.

Comment: I suspect the dual O2 sensors are the least of your problems.  Even on a speed-density system, something has to rewrite the EEC-IV fuel maps to compensate for the loss of 1 liter of displacement.  Has somebody already done this conversion and you are following that lead?  It's one thing to swap CFI out for a carb on a Mustang 302.  Yet quite another to lose 25% of the displacement and hope the EEC will learn and compensate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drill and tap the other manifold, or have a good welder braze or weld an O2 bung somewhere accessible.  However, please see my comments above... maybe I can improve this answer.

This sounds like a cool project, and I don't want to discourage it, but there may be more than just mounting the throttle body and expecting correct Air/Fuel ratios without ECU  (EEC-IV) remapping.  Possibly you could fudge a little with coolant temp sensor resistors and possibly throttle position sensor... but I doubt a manifold pressure drop of say, 2psi on the 2.8 equates to the same CFM (and needed fuel injection) as the 3.8 mapping.  I *could* be wrong, if the intake manifold configuration is very similar.

Just keep in mind that a 25% reduction in displacement translates to a 25% reduction in airflow CFM for any given RPM.  The airflow is *calculated* from the signal of pressure drop of the MAP (manifold pressure sensor) and is only valid for that particular manifold. The information is scaled in the EEC-IV along with RPM and throttle position, to determine the proper fuel injector (in your case central, single-point) pulse width.

None of that was an answer to your original question... but I'd rather not send you down a path if there are other monsters to be slayed first.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely a bit weary of the conversion just from the fairly large differences between the engines. But there's been several people that have already done it. I'm basically using these instructions: http://www.therangerstation.com/tech_library/2_8_FuelInjection.shtml